# Fetch matched object from JSON column with an array of object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, mysql-json

I have a json column with the following array:

```
[  
   {
     "name":"Raj",
     "email":"raj@gmail.com",
     "age":32
      
   },
   {
     "name":"Mohan",
     "email":"Mohan@yahoo.com",
     "age":21
      
   }   
]
```

I want to get an object whose name is Raj.
Output :

```
[  
 {
 "name":"Raj",
 "email":"raj@gmail.com",
 "age":32
 } 
]
```

Can you help me for MYSQL query for this?

Comment: JSON data type has specific documentation page about how to use it (update, query…). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: @BaptisteDonaux Yes, I know there is documentation. But not able to get this result.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do this with MySQL 8.0. But you can extract value of a JSON value. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract With this, you can determine JSON which contains a specific value.